# How do I iterate over a vector and also know the index of the element?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl, iteration

I need to access each element in a vector and also know what index the element is in.

So far I could come up with two ways

```
 for (iterator it= aVector.begin(), int index= 0; it!= aVector.end(); ++it, ++index)
```

leaving the type signature. also it looks like i can't use auto

```
 for (int index = 0; index < aVector.size(); ++index)
{
    // access using []
}
```

Which one is more efficient or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you *need* the index for some intrinsic, fundamental reason, then use the second version.

Comment: Yes, prefer the latter if you need index.

Comment: _"Which one is more efficient?"_ Why not just put it in a loop and measure the time? As far as personal preference, I'd go with the second one ... always. Just look how ugly the first one is.

Comment: You could also use [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) if you can't control where the iterator is coming from and don't want to write the loop yourself. But really it is just looping from the first to the second and counting, nothing special. (EDIT: actually, it's not in the `vector` case, it's cheating and using the fact that it really is just an array underneath).

Comment: @BoBTFish: It's not "cheating", or using the fact that it's an array; it's using the fact that the iterator is random-access, as the standard says it must.

Comment: The first won't compile, so I say the second one.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For a vector or other random-access container, it makes little difference. I would probably choose the second because it's easier to read, and is probably marginally faster since there's only one loop variable to update. Another alternative is:

```cpp
for (auto it = aVector.begin(); it != aVector.end(); ++it) {
    int index = std::distance(aVector.begin(), it);
}
```

For non-random-access containers, `[]` isn't available, and `std::distance` is inefficient; in that case, if you need the index, the first method would be better (although you'll need to fix it so it doesn't try to declare two differently-typed variables in the for-initialiser).

Comment: Now that's what I meant to say :p

Comment: This should be fixed to reflect the fact that `std::distance` returns `std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::difference_type`, which is going to be a wider type than an `int`. (The fact that few people will have containers large enough to overflow an `int` is not an excuse.) Another reason just to use `auto` - it's weird that you did for `it` but not for `index`.

Answer (score 12):

Another way.

```
int count = 0;
for (auto& it : aVector) {
   count++;
}
```

Comment: First I thought to myself, "surely, with eight answers, someone's already mentioned this; after all, it's the most simple and straightforward approach." Nope. +1 to you.

Answer (score 11):

The answer is in the question - *"know what index the element is in."*.

So -

```
for (int index = 0; index < aVector.size(); ++index)
{
    // access using []
}
```

Performance-wise they're the same (but you can always profile yourself).

Comment: index should be `size_t` instead of `int`

Comment: @Rémi pedantically, it should be vector<T>::size_type :)

Comment: @Rémi is there a reason why one might want to use size_t instead of int?

Comment: Yes. In most modern compilers, int is 32 bits, and size_t is 64 bits. So using int won't work if you have a very big vector.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using `zip_iterator` and `counting_iterator` from the [Boost.Iterator library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/). It is probably *way* overkill for your use case, but it has the advantages of working with any range (not only vectors) and to fit it nicely with the iterator-based design of standard algorithms, so I post it here:

```
#include <boost/iterator/counting_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp>

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main()
{
    typedef std::list<int> container;

    typedef boost::tuple<
        container::iterator,
        boost::counting_iterator<container::size_type>
    > tuple_type;

    typedef boost::zip_iterator<tuple_type> it_type;

    container l{1, 2, 3, 4};

    it_type begin(tuple_type(l.begin(), 0));
    it_type const end(tuple_type(l.end(), l.size()));

    // sample use with for loop
    for (it_type it = begin; it != end ; ++it)
    {
        int value = it->get<0>();
        int index = it->get<1>();
        // do whatever you want with value and index
    }

    // sample use with standard algorithm
    auto res = std::find_if(begin, end,
        [](boost::tuple<int, int> const & t)
        { return t.get<0>() > 2; }); // find first element greater than 2

    std::cout << "Value: " << res->get<0>() << '\n' <<
                 "Index: " << res->get<1>() << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use Boost.Range's `indexed` adaptor, which extends the range's iterators with an `index` method that returns the current index (duh).

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/indexed.hpp>

// ...
auto&& r = vec | boost::adaptors::indexed(0);
for(auto it(begin(r)), ite(end(r)); it != ite; ++it)
  std::cout << it.index() << ": " << *it << "\n";
```

Sadly, since `index` is part a method on the iterator, this means you can't use the new range-based for loop or even `BOOST_FOREACH`, which only give element access. Here's a rather boilerplate-y workaround of questionable value:

```
// note: likely contains typos or bugs
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>

template<class IndexIt>
auto pair_index_value(IndexIt it)
    -> std::pair<std::size_t, decltype(*it)>
{
  return std::pair<std::size_t, decltype(*it)>(it.index(), *it);
}

// ...
using namespace boost::adaptors;

auto&& ir = vec | indexed; // because screw you Boost.Range
for(auto&& elem : boost::counting_range(ir.begin(), ir.end()) | transformed(pair_index_value))
  std::cout << elem.first << ": " << elem.second << "\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

With C++23 and `std::views::enumerate`, indexed iteration is now extremely convenient. Below is an example:

```cpp
#include <print>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector constants { 3.141, 1.414, 1.618 };
  for (auto const& [index, constant] : constants | std::views::enumerate) {
    std::print("{}: {}", index, constant); // std::print is another C++23 goodie!
  }
}
```

The [cppreference.com page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/enumerate_view) on `std::views::enumerate` provides more detailed information. The [relevant episode of C++ Weekly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HuRbLPRh-Nk) is also useful for learning how to try out such bleeding-edge features in Compiler Explorer if you have not had the chance to avail of it before.

Note: To get the code example to compile at the time of writing, I used x86 MSVC v19.latest with compiler flag `/std:c++latest`.

Answer (score 2):

c++11:

```
for (auto i=aVector.begin(); i!=aVector.end(); ++i) {
    cout << "I am at position: " << i-aVector.begin() << endl;
    cout << "contents here is: " << *i << endl;
}
```

c++ old school:

```
for (vector<int>::const_iterator i=aVector.begin(); i!=aVector.end(); ++i) {
    cout << "I am at position: " << i-aVector.begin() << endl;
    cout << "contents here is: " << *i << endl;
}
```

Comment: In the first one, `i` is the element of the vector, not an index or iterator. You can't get the index from a range-style for loop. (In the case of a vector, you could hack it with `&i-&vector[0]`, but that will break silently and horribly if the container type changes, so don't do it).

Comment: @MikeSeymour I think your hack would only work (?) if the for-loop was using `for (auto& i : aVector)`, otherwise, as it is written now, `i` is a copy of the element in the vector.

Comment: @BrianNeal: So it is. That's another reason not to do it.

Comment: updated to a working one. It's a shame the auto thing wouldn't work in this case; that would have been cool.

Comment: @matiu Don't leave the broken one there, just delete it and show the better version.

Answer (score 2):

To be a little pendantic, the OP's first statement doesn't compile because of the way the comma operator works.  I'm sure the OP was just using a shorthand for `iterator` instead of the full typename, but that isn't the problem:

```
for (iterator it= aVector.begin(), int index= 0; it!= aVector.end(); ++it, ++index)
```

The comma operator either separates two expressions (and returns the result of the second expression), or it is used to separate variables in a declaration.  The first argument of the for argument will take either form, so it is obfuscates the fact that they are different syntaxes.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> aVector = {1,1,2,3,5,8,13};

    // option 1. Both loop variables declared outside the for statement, initialized inside the for statement
    int index1 = 0;
    decltype(aVector.begin()) it1;
    for (it1 = aVector.begin(), index1=0; it1!= aVector.end(); ++it1, ++index1)
    {
        std::cout << "[" << index1 << "]=" << *it1 << std::endl;
    }

    // option 2. The index variable declared and initialized outside, the iterator declared and initialized inside
    int index2=0;
    for (auto it2 = aVector.begin(); it2!= aVector.end(); ++it2, ++index2)
    {
        std::cout << "[" << index2 << "]=" << *it2 << std::endl;
    }

#if 0
    // option3 (the OP's version) won't compile. The comma operator doesn't allow two declarations.
    for (auto it3 = aVector.begin(), int index3=0 ; it3!= aVector.end(); ++it3, ++index3)
    {
        std::cout << "[" << index3 << "]=" << *it3 << std::endl;
    }
#endif
}
```

Comment: Well, [Fiktik observed this back in 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495382/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-vector-and-also-know-the-index-of-the-element/67577819#comment16813920_12495478).

Comment: I was showing the two options to get close to the OP's intended syntax of his example, and expanding on Fiktik's answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (iterator it = aVector.begin(), int index= 0; it!= aVector.end(); ++it, ++index)
```

This will not compile. But it doesn't really matter, because as long as we are talking about `std::vector` then accessing by index is a simple pointer arithmetic and dereference - so in reality as fast as with the iterator. So your version 2 is OK.

I would however further optimize (if you are really concerned about speed):

```
for (int index = 0, size = aVector.size(); index < size; ++index)
{
    // access using []
}
```

Comment: Why doesnt the first one compile? did you put in the correct iterator type?

Comment: @kunj2aan: Because you can't declare variables of unrelated types (`iterator` and `int`) in a single declaration.

Comment: @kunj2aan Why don't you just [try it](http://ideone.com/DF6TG). Note the [solution is simple](http://ideone.com/yw5Lw).